# ZSH PATH variable entries are backwards on OS X Catalina

Tags: macos, path, zsh

So I just installed macOS Catalina and MacPorts. This caused me to have to modify the PATH and MANPATH enviroment variables in my .zshenv file as follows:

```
# configure an environment variable for Racket
export RACKET=/Applications/Racket

# configure an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$RACKET/bin:$PATH"

# configure an appropriate MANPATH variable for use with MacPorts
export MANPATH="/opt/local/share/man:$RACKET/man:$MANPATH"
```

However, running the following command `echo $PATH` gives me the reverse of what I'd expect:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/Racket/bin
```

Any ideas on what I should do to remedy this? The fact that the entires for `/opt/local/*` are towards the end are breaking some build scripts for quite a utilities that I use.

Comment: I would recommend you to choose @yinz Liu as the answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that `.zshenv` executes before any other startup files, which are also modifying `PATH`. (This isn't a full explanation, as `/etc/zprofile` should be overwriting `PATH`, not prepending to it. But it's close.)

Instead of setting `PATH` in `.zshenv` (which is sourced for *all* shells, interactive or not), do it in `~/.zprofile` instead.

See the section on startup/shutdown files in `man zsh` for a full explanation of which files are sourced and when.

Answer (score 7):

Add code below in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile`:

```sh
# Prepend the $PATH
[[ -f $HOME/.zshenv ]] && source $HOME/.zshenv 
# remove duplicate $PATH
typeset -U PATH
```

Explanation:

According to the [zsh loading order](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/), for any login-shell in zsh, it would call `etc/zprofile` after `~/.zshenv` but before `~/.zshrc`,
which contains [usr/libexec/path_helper](https://gist.github.com/gilaras/159792/153e5e602cff73eeb53f9dbc4e0f479296b75ddf):

```sh
 # file: etc/zprofile
 # system-wide environment settings for zsh(1)
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
   eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

The code above moves the `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` ahead of your self-added `$PATH` such as `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin..`.

We source the `.zshenv` again after the `/etc/zprofile` to add self-added path to the front again , `type -U PATH` keep the `path` remain at the first place appeared and remove duplicate one.

Comment: Could I set `export PATH="...:$PATH"` in `~/.zprofile` instead of using `[[ -f ~/.zshenv ]] && source ~/.zshenv`? Which one is preferred?

Comment: it's OK for adding several path conveniently. I usually put system path at the last so I source .zshenv again.